# Pass argument to a fragment from ASyncTask

Tags: android, fragment, bundle

I am working on an application in which i get data from server and parse it in **AsyncTask** in **MainActivity** 
Then i call another activity named **DetailsPage** which have fragments.
 here is how i am calling and passing argument to DetailsPage. this is called in AsyncTask.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailsPage.class);
                    myIntent.putExtra("adminId",adminId);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
```

then in DetailPage i am getting these argument and putting it in bundle for fragment run by DetailsPage.

```
public class DetailsPage extends FragmentActivity implements
        ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Payments", "Goods" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details_page);
        /*Get Extra Values from the mainActivity*/
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String value = extras.getString("adminId");
            Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("adminId", value);
            PaymentsFragment payment_frag=new PaymentsFragment();
            payment_frag.setArguments(bundle);
        }
        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }

        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                // on changing the page
                // make respected tab selected
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // on tab selected
        // show respected fragment view
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

and in PaymentsFragment i am trying to get the string from bundle inside **oncreateView**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
/*Get Extras Passed by MainActivity*/
        adminId=getArguments().getString(adminId);
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_payments, container, false);
        CustomListView = this;
        String serverURL = "http://ott.edgeaccounts.com/Webservices/GetPaymentService.php";
        new GetPayments().execute(serverURL);
        Resources res =getResources(); 
        list=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_payments);
        adapter=new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArr,res);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

but it gives null pointer exception in this line
**adminId=getArguments().getString(adminId);**
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Use getIntent() you are storing your string in an Intent not a bundle

Comment: Did you initialize adminId

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
adminId=getArguments().getString(adminId);
```

to

```
adminId=getArguments().getString("adminId");
```

cause the key is "adminId"

```
bundle.putString("adminId", value); // in quotes adminId
```

You can reference

[Send data from activity to fragment in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: @R WOW! That was fast. +1

Comment: @user3297557 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString(java.lang.String). There is no value with that key then getString returns null

Comment: That is unfair if your answer didn't work for me it doesn't mean you downvote my question

Comment: @user3297557 who said i downvoted. I din't. If you feel that way i am sorry. Its upto you to accept or not accept. I don't have a say if others downvote. By the way i linked to the docs and the docs is the best place to look for concrete answers

Comment: this was not meant for you @Raghunandan

Comment: @user3297557 the don't comment under my post